# PHP variable passing

Tags: php, drupal

I'm working with drupal. I have this page something.com/node/13. Inside I have this script

```
 <?php
 $door = $_GET["variable"];
 echo $door;
 ?>
```

When I open the URL like this something.com/node/13?variable=1231 I get the following error:

```
  Error message
  Notice: Undefined index: variable in eval() (line 2 of /var/www/html/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
```

and no output. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That error is not from the code posted here.  Why are you using `eval`?  What is the whole code?

Comment: Try `$door = isset($_GET["variable"]) ? $_GET["variable"] : '';`  Did you call the URL like `something.com/node/13?variable=x`?  If you did, then Drupal is unsetting values in the $_GET array and presumably moving them somewhere else.

Comment: Possibly an absent `[QSA]` flag in the RewriteRules, so the `?variable=xx` isn't carried on to the target script.

Comment: @Rocket I think Drupal is calling `eval()` in order to run the PHP code that the user has added to that particular page in the CMS.

Comment: @drew010: Really?  Like, really?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359240/php-get-and-post-undefined-problem

Comment: @Rocket Yea, check out `drupal-7.14/modules/block/block.module`

Comment: Please post all your code, because the error isn't from this one.

Comment: @drew010 I tried your snipet. The error went away but now when I call the url there is no output. Which makes sense because if it's not set, that line sets it to "". My question is why isn't it setting it?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann - yes it is. The index "variable" is undefined within $_GET. As mario says, this is probably [QSA] missing from the mod_access rules.

Comment: To the OP - what is contained in the $_GET['q'] variable? (http://drupal.org/node/180589)

Comment: @sugonamission node/31 which I know is diffrent from my original post but thats because I didn't bother to see the node number.

Comment: @sugonamission How would I fix the mod_access rules? Or what would I have to do in order to be able to pass this variable?

Comment: Never mind guys. Thanks to @slugonamission for that link he posted. I just used $door = arg(1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error, partcilarly in drupal 7 simply means that you aren't getting any value for $_GET['variable'].  This would be because the url doesn't have a value (someurl?variable=foo).  You can avoid the notice by prefixing an @ like this:

$door = @$_GET['variable'];

but that won't make the variable return any data.   It's pretty unclear from the code you've posted what you're trying to accomplish.  You might consider starting there. There is no reason why you can't use $_GET variables in drupal.   I do so all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [drupal_get_query_parameters](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7)

Because the rewrite rules with Drupal, you don't grab the $_GET values cleanly directly like that.